# Is there a way where all the values from a JSON column can be used as query params to fetch values in db?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a lookup table with columns old_item_code, description, new_item_code.

Now my *items* is an array of objects.

```
"items":[
  {
    "code": "OLDCODE1",
    "description": "sample description1",
    "value": "Sample value1"
  },
  {
    "code": "OLDCODE2",
    "description": "Sample Description2",
    "value": "Sample Value 2"
  }
]
```

Now I want my items array to be replaced with new item code which has to be queried from the lookup table(postgres).

I want my final result to be like

```
"items": [
    {
      "NEWCODE1": "Sample Value 1",
      "NewCODE2": "Sample Value 2"
    }
   ]
```

Comment: You will need to provide more details. What is the result you are looking for? How does this lookup table look like? How can you join that lookup table with the target table you want to change? What is the data type of that column? Can you setup a [fiddle script](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) with some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

In PSQL, using where with array will get you the new code. Use a map to get its values.